Create new "Properties" Custom-Action
I use the "Properties" option a lot for file information and it annoys me that it's right at the bottom of the Right-Click menu. I know how to create 'Custom-Actions' and that they can be moved UP or DOWN the menu list. 
Instead of "Run Command" I would like a "Properties" item which I can move up the list.
Linux-Mint 21.3 (File Manager - Thunar)
I came up with this so far.  but the cannibalized code yad --info --title="File Properties for %n" --text="$(echo; echo -n 'INFO-1: ' 'stat' %n | awk '{print $1}'; echo; echo 'INFO-2:' ls -l %n | awk '{print $1}')" --width=350 --height=280 --center --button=gtk-close
Only produces: 
The "stat" command is not producing data, just titles. I'd point it at the "Properties" bin file and get same result as: but I don't think there is one. Suggestions welcomed.

Clicking on the file/folder to highlight it and then pressing Alt+Return won't do the trick for you?

I'm aware of the keyboard shortcut. I was wondering if there was the ability to create a 'Custom Action' as well. If there is a "Run Command" option in the menu, can't the command be "Show Properties" ?
